# Filtering Data Based on Whether Zeroes Ever Appear (Across Many Rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

Consider the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    cost decimal(10,2),
    ref int
);

INSERT INTO my_table(cost, ref)
VALUES      (0.00, 1),
            (0.50, 1),
            (-1.89, 1),
            (0.00, 2),
            (0.00, 2),
            (0.00, 2),
            (1.23, 3),
            (-9.47, 3),
            (111.23, 3),
            (12.00, 3);
```

My aim with this table is to filter it to remove all rows where `ref = 2` (rows 4, 5, and 6 in the above), because all of the cost values where `ref = 2` are zero.

I've got halfway there by working out which values of `ref` have AT LEAST one row where cost is not zero:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ref
INTO            refs_to_keep
FROM            my_table
WHERE           cost != 0.00;
```

So what I'd like then like to do to finish the job is something like

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE ref NOT IN "list of refs in the refs_to_keep table";
```

But I don't know the syntax for that. Can anyone help me out please?

Or maybe there's another way to achieve this without the intermediate `refs_to_keep` stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you are pretty much there already although you don't need to create the temp table you can just use a sub-query:

```
delete from my_table
where ref not in 
(
  select distinct ref
  from my_table
  where cost <> 0
)
```

You can see it working here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fAYuenfopm4BkYFRNMKY9w/0

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a nice simple solution (I'm an SQL beginner and I can follow it ok). Will try it out today.

Comment: Yep. It works. Nice. Thanks again.

Comment: No probs, you were SO close! :) Just one thing to note, which maybe because you have anonymised the table, but also might be because you are new to sql, avoid using reserved keywords for column/table names. They can end up being a right PITA. You can check them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Be careful if ref can be null. The `distinct` is redundant of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the windowed function `SUM` to find the rows with a total of 0:

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE (cost decimal(10,2), ref int);

INSERT INTO @my_table(cost, ref) VALUES      (0.00, 1),
(0.50, 1), (1.89, 1), (0.00, 2), (0.00, 2),
(0.00, 2), (1.23, 3), (9.47, 3), (111.23, 3),
(12.00, 3);

DELETE a
  FROM (
        SELECT *, SUM(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as sumCost
          FROM @my_table
       ) a
 WHERE sumCost = 0;

SELECT *
  FROM @my_table;
```

| cost | ref |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 1 |
| 0.50 | 1 |
| 1.89 | 1 |
| 1.23 | 3 |
| 9.47 | 3 |
| 111.23 | 3 |
| 12.00 | 3 |

Here we're using the windowed `SUM` function to find the rows with a total of 0 (ORDER BY (SELECT 1) is a kludge to total each row). Once we know the rows, they can be deleted.

Edit:

```
DECLARE @my_table TABLE (cost decimal(10,2), ref int);

INSERT INTO @my_table(cost, ref) VALUES      (0.00, 1),
(0.50, 1), (1.89, 1), (0.00, 2), (0.00, 2),
(0.00, 2), (1.23, 3), (-9.47, 3), (111.23, 3),
(12.00, 3), (10,4), (-10,4);

DELETE a
  FROM (
        SELECT *, MAX(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as maCost, MIN(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as miCost
          FROM @my_table
       ) a
 WHERE miCost = 0
   AND maCost = 0;

SELECT *
  FROM @my_table;
```

| cost | ref |
| --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 1 |
| 0.50 | 1 |
| 1.89 | 1 |
| 1.23 | 3 |
| -9.47 | 3 |
| 111.23 | 3 |
| 12.00 | 3 |
| 10.00 | 4 |
| -10.00 | 4 |

This now looks for a MIN and MAX of 0, using a similar technique. I added a 4th set of values where one was 10 and the other -10 to provide an example of a set which would have been deleted using the previous method.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately (and I'll edit my example to show this in a second - my mistake) the `cost` amounts can be negative as well as positive, so a zero `sumCost` for a given `ref` doesn't necessarily mean that all rows have zeroes in them.

Comment: I'll wait for your amended example, but if we want to exclude all rows where there is only a 0 (keep the positives and negatives) we can probably perform much the same, but using a `MIN` and `MAX` windowed functions where they are both 0.

Comment: Yes - I think that would work

Comment: `SUM(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY ref) without an `ORDER BY surely?

Comment: I would swear that, at least some point, you were required to use an ORDER BY for windowed functions, and I never tried without it again since it was so easy to work around. You are correct, at least in 2022 you can omit the order by all together.

Comment: With an `ORDER BY` is something enirely different: a cumulative sum. Without gives you the same result across the whole `PARTITION BY`. I don't believe you ever needed `ORDER BY`.

Comment: `SELECT B, C, SUM(C) OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), SUM(C) OVER (PARTITION BY B) FROM (VALUES (1,2),(1,2),(2,1)) a(B, C)` - `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` returns a cumulative sum, the same as omitting it. It is not incorrect, just superfluous. I think the error I recall may be from `ROW_NUMBER()` and **I** applied it to all windowed functions.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you could simply delete rows where there are no non-zero lines for a ref?

```
delete from t
from my_table t
where not exists (
  select * from my_table t2 
  where t2.ref = t.ref and t2.cost != 0
);
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TR6nfCBq)